# Adding user input, very simple

Tags: racket, r5rs

I need to use user input to run a program. I don't understand this program completely. How do I get an error of 4 inputs while I'm only asking for 2 inputs?

```
        ; Q4: Please enter test values 2 and 5. It should return 32. (5 
             points)
             (display "Enter 2 5 as test case. It returns 32")
            (newline)
             (define (ReadForPower
              ; Enter your code here
             x y)(Power(x y)))

              (ReadForPower display(read) display(read))
```

Power is a function that simply uses recursion to find power. It has 2 parameters, 2 integers, x, and y.

Comment: it needs to take in user input

Comment: You're getting 4 arguments because 

`display` is your first argument, `(read)` is your second, `display` third, `(read)` fourth.

Comment: so just typing read takes in user input?

Comment: Yes, you can remove both the `display`s. `(read)` will take in user input.

Comment: i get the following error

Comment: application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: 2
  arguments...:

Comment: does read mean its an int parameter?

Comment: change `(Power(x y))` to `(Power x y)`. The first one says apply function `Power` to the application of `y` on `x`. The second says apply 2 arguments `x` and `y` onto function `Power`.